# Modify Path Param of an HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, servlets

I have a method which processes that URL:

```
http://IP:PORT/auth/myapp?Username=username
```

and accessible from remote. However I can not change external system which uses my app and it sends username within HTTP Header. I mean they access that URL:

```
http://IP:PORT/auth/myapp
```

I think that I can get related HTTP Header as follows:

```
Enumeration headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
while(headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
    String headerName = (String)headerNames.nextElement();
    if (headerName.equals("UNAME")) {
        String username = request.getHeader(headerName);
    }   
}
```

I can not modify whole part of my app and I have to add that info as path parameter into existing request. I mean change that request to:

```
http://IP:PORT/auth/myapp?Username=username
```

How can I do that?

**PS:**
Can this piece of code solve the problem that I've described?

```
if (request.getParameter("Username") == null) {
    Enumeration headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
    while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
        String headerName = (String) headerNames.nextElement();
        if (headerName.equals("UNAME")) {
            String username = request.getHeader(headerName);
            response.sendRedirect(request.getRequestURI() + "&Username="+username);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are accessing 'username' query parameter using HttpServletRequest.getParameter('username') in other parts of your app, you can try using [HttpServletRequestWrapper](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html)

```
class MyRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper{

    public String getParameter(String name){
        // if name equals username, call super.getHeader('username')
        //else super.getParameter(name);
    }
}
```

You can extend this class and override getParameter() method. In your implementation, you get the value from header if parameter name is username else call the super method.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is two solutions:

1. Use a filter on your application mapped on each request. The filter will check header and add a parameter if the UNAME header is there
2. Use Apache Rewrite Module in front of your web application. Rewrite module will add the parameter to the url (check "Module Apache mod_rewrite")

**UPDATE:** As mohit said used a HttpRequestWrapper combined with a filter

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse,
        FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        //create the MyCustomWrapperRequest object to wrap the HttpServletRequest
        MyCustomWrapperRequest request = new MyCustomWrapperRequest((HttpServletRequest)servletRequest);
        //continue on in the filter chain
        filterChain.doFilter(request, servletResponse);
}
```

And in MyCustomWrapperRequest override getParameter() function

Comment: I've added a PS to my question. Could you check it?

Comment: I think redirect it's a bad idea because you will have twice request more on your application.

Comment: You are right. However when I check which class to extend I see that it is: `weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl` due to Weblogic is used. So, if I switch from Weblogic it will be a bad practice. What do you think?

Comment: You need to extend javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper not weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl

Answer (score 0):

It's round-a-bout, but if you also have the HttpServletResponse object, you can send a redirect request to the http://IP:PORT/auth/myapp?Username=username URL

Comment: I've added a PS to my question. Could you check it?